# Running iis7 with xampp

Tags: php, iis, asp-classic, xampp, intranet

I currently develop under iis for classic asp for my work experience although for uni I'm required to do php. I have iis set up on my comp and installed xampp, after restarting my computer local host is not working for me. I read up somewhere that i need to change ports so i changed iis port to port 8080 but to access my sites now i have to type in http://localhost:8080/Test/login.asp instead of localhost/test/login.asp is there a way to have it so i don't need to type in the port number as well?

Comment: PHP is compatible with IIS, don't overcomplicate it by installing XAMPP. http://windows.php.net/

Comment: @Richard Knop I personally think its a good idea to keep the technology where it belongs, asp on IIS and PHP on Apache. Also its great to get the experience of both web servers, but thats just my opinion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, two different web servers have to listen on different ports. The standard HTTP port is 80. If you set another (here 8080) you have to type it the URL.

But you can install [PHP for IIS](http://php.iis.net/) so your would not need xampp at all.

Comment: just a little more on to why this cant be done not just it cant be
When you start a server it has to bind to a port what this means is it is listing on that port for a incoming connection if you could have another on the same port how would each application know what was for it or for the other application

Answer (score 3):

Web servers use port 80 by default. As you have 2 web servers now, only one can use the port 80. So there is no other way around using the second webserver without the additional port address in there.

A work around might be to set both web servers to start manually (via the services administration panel). So based on what you are working on start only the one you want.